# How can I diagnose my fridge's evaporator fan?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

How can I find out which part has failed in my fridge? The evaporator fan at the back of the freezer is not working, so the freezer is cold but the fridge is not. How can I figure out if it's the fan or some other (hopefully less expensive) part?

Comment: Any chance it's just the fan motor? I had a dead one on a brand new refrigerator.

Comment: Fan motor on my new fridge died after about 6 months. Repair isn't too expensive if you replace the fan yourself. The fridge companies do NOT waste money on putting a quality motor back there.

Answer (score 2):

If the fan is not working, you need to focus on that first.

- If you spin it manually, does it work? If so, the motor may just be old or clogged so starting friction is too high - try cleaning, then replace.
- If you cannot spin it, check for obstruction. If none, replace.
- Check voltage across the fan motor (with door switch open then closed) - if it doesn't turn on, then check electricals.

(It is a cheap and easy self repair)

Once you have got the fan working again, then check to see if problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If the Fan is not working, the refrigerator part will not get cold, but you have to take in consideration that it is connected to a switch and the fan gets disconnected when you open the freezer door. Look for the switch and press it whit your hand to determine if is working or not.

If you see ice build up at the back of the freezer it could be stopping the fan and the will indicate that there is a problem with one of the defrost components. And